# How to register custom HostnameVerifier in Java 8

Tags: java, ssl, https

I have a project with Java 6 where this code works as expected

```
HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {

    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
         return true;
    }
};
System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
```

However in another project which uses Java 8 this does not work as `HostnameVerifier.verify` never gets invoked. Both projects use `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactory` to create service instance in order to execute requests for 3rd party API

Comment: If your goal is to allow connections to sites with invalid SSL certificates, you’ll need more than a HostnameVerifier.  You’ll need to set the [SSLContext](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) to a context initialized with a TrustManager that overrides all of its checks.

Comment: Why do you remove the test on hostname? Doing so makes you vulnerable to attacks as basically any certificate becomes valid, no matter what. Doing that makes you loose almost all usefulness of HTTPS and you are as good as using HTTP.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek because on my local develepoment environment I am using SSH tunnel to be able to acceess this 3rd party API so URL to send requests to becomes h-ttps://localhost:some_port/...

Comment: @VGR is this what has changed since Java 6? Because in the project with Java 6 TrustManager and SSLContext classes are only used in utility class (needs to be run manually, etc from CMD) for helping developer to install certificates by just providing URL so that no manual work of putting certificates in cacerts would be required. Other than that, TrustManager and SSLContext are not used anywhere.

Comment: "so URL to send requests to becomes h-ttps://localhost:some_port/... "  So don't do that. Use a real hostname. Either in `/etc/hosts` or in the global DNS.

Comment: I prefer working around this host problem via code and not local environment machine config as other developers will also need to do changes to their hosts file. When workaround is in the code I can check weather this application is in development mode because application config has a flag for this. So when other developers take over my work they will checkout code from repository and the development config will be there so other developers will not need to have inconvenience of handling this issue.